# how can i trigger action by span id?

Tags: jquery

How can I trigger action by `<span id=` in jquery?

my html:

```
<span id="span-1"></span>
<span id="span-2"></span>
<span id="span-3"></span>
<span id="span-4"></span>
```

what i've tried

```
$('[id^="span-"]').click(function () {
        alert("this_id");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `this.id` make sure you include required jQuery library and put code in document.ready

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdcPW/)**

```
$('[id^="span-"]').click(function () {
        alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#spanid').click(function () {
     alert(this.id);
});
```

i.e.

```
$('#span-2').click(function () {
     alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: I think he wants to target all spans starting with part of an id (span-)

Comment: Ahh, misread the question then, figured it wasn't that simple!